# C outputting "{" when reading from file

Tags: c

I have written this code using Xcode to read from a file:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{       
    FILE *fp = fopen("hello.rtf", "r");

    printf("%c\n", fgetc(fp));

    fclose(fp);

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file!");
        return 1;
    }

    // insert code here...
    return 0;
}
```

The character that I get is "{" and it is not the first character in the file.

Comment: `.rtf` Rich text format file is not a file of text as it is. see Code example of [rich text format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I've changed the file extension to .txt, but still getting the same output.

Comment: It is the difference in format of the contents is not a problem with the file extension. I think it is that we should re-saved as a text open in the editor that can read rich text file.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY it just worked !!! thanks, man.

Comment: The file extension just helps the OS choosing the correct program for opening that file. It's not related to the content of the file. You can rename an *.mp4 file to any extension like *.doc, *.txt, *.xyz... and it can still be opened without problem in any media players provided that it has the correct header in the file.

Answer (score 5):

The RTF spec says that the first character in an RTF file should be `{`, so it seems that you are getting the expected result. Bear in mind that a word processing software will not show you the exact characters in the file, but it will show you the formatted text which has been described by the [markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) characters in the file.

To see the exact characters in the file you could output it with `cat` (POSIX) or `type` (DOS / Windows command prompt).

The `if (fp == NULL)` check should go immediately after the `fopen` line; by the end it's too late.